# Adjust scrollview height based on other layouts visibility

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an app with a custom "keyboard", which basically is a layout with some buttons that pops up from the bottom when user is about to do some input. The main view consists of a scrollview with some other components in it. The problem is that when the user is about to make some input and the keyboard is made visible I can't get the scrollviews height to automatically adjust to the available height when the keyboard is shown, which causes the keyboard to be shown above the main UI. See picture of this behavior.

[image: Actual behavior]

What I'm looking for is the same behavior that `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` makes, but since I'm not using the systems softkeyboard as input I have no use for that tag.

To hide and show my keyboard I use `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE`.
XML for my UI is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".activity.RunnersCalculator">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/input_sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pace_to_speed_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:text="@string/convert_xx_to_xx"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHeadingText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pace_to_speed_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ax.stardust.runcal.component.KeyboardlessEditText
                android:id="@+id/pace_to_speed_et"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/input_default"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="@string/default_pace"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorInputText"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/input_cursor_default" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pace_to_speed_results_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="100"
                android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                android:text="@string/pace_to_speed_results"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <!-- rest of components omitted -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <ax.stardust.runcal.component.RunnersKeyboard
        android:id="@+id/soft_keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ax.stardust.runcal.component.RunnersKeyboard>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/author"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/version_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/author_tv"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/version_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="8sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is this even doable only by using XML, or do I need to do this programmatically? Any tips on this problem is highly appreciated as I'm kind of stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put both RunnersKeyboard and ScrollView as children to your parent layout,

```
<LinearLayout 

<ScrollView


<RunnersKeyboard

</LinearLayout>
```

you can put both RunnersKeyboard and scrollView weights to 1 and height to 0dp so they take half of your full screen, and when you set the RunnersKeyboard visibility to gone the ScrollView will take the whole screen

Comment: I actually have both the scrollview and runnerskeyboard as children of a relative layout. That info must have gone lost when I copied the snippet, will update the code.

Comment: what about putting them in a linearLayout and use layout weight ?

Comment: Tried it a bit and I'm halfway there now, problem is now that the scrollview got a fixed height, I would like it to expand when the keyboard isn't visible. Will test this  solution a bit more

Comment: Ended up using your solution, worked as a charm after a bit of tweaking :)

Comment: @Robert You should post your tweaked solution as an answer so others can use it too.

Comment: @J.D. take a look at the full source here https://github.com/rnyholm/runcalc/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_calculator.xml

Comment: Great thank you very much! (I actually didn't expect a response, especially so quickly, for something a year and a half old lol.)